# Yesod ghc.exe not responding when doing "yesod devel" Windows

Tags: windows, haskell, cabal, yesod, haskell-platform

I was starting to read about Yesod on Yesod website, and I tried to install it on Windows.

I followed the following steps :

1. I installed Haskell-Platform from their website for Windows.
2. I added C:...\AppData\Roaming\cabal\bin on my Path (where "..." means my HOME folder).
3. I opened my Command Prompt and typed "cabal update"
4. Then I did "cabal install cabal-install" to install the newest version.
5. Afterwards, I executed "cabal install yesod" and everything worked fine.
6. Called "yesod init" and it created my projet.
7. Finally called "yesod devel" and the problem started.

Once I call "yesod devel" I have the following error :
Desktop\yosod>yesod devel
Yesod devel server. Press ENTER to quit
Configurating yosod-0.0.0 (yosod is the name of my application)
yesod: src\System\Win32\Notify.hs:(136,1)-(146,45): Non-exhaustive patterns function 
actsToEvent

Rebuilding application... (using Cabal library)
Starting development server...
Starting devel application
Exit code: ExitFailure 255

(Then there's a window popup saying : ghc.exe not responding)

"ghc --version" is 7.4.2 
"cabal --version" : 
cabal-install version 1.16.0.2 
using version 1.16.0.3 of the Cabal library

I tried reinstalling everything and I had the same error. 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: I opened an issue against the relevant package about this bug: https://github.com/mdittmer/win32-notify/issues/1. Unfortunately it hasn't been solved yet.

Comment: You should try using `cabal install yesod-platform` instead (after cleaning up everything, as it cannot be run after `cabal install yesod`), it solved a very similar issue I had.

Answer (score 2):

The upstream bug should now be resolved.